# Run CMake to generate C++ project twice, the vcxproj.filters files are different

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

Just run CMake twice or several times to generate the same C++ project without any changes, but the vcxproj.filters are changed.
The order and guids of the filters are not stable.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Filter Include="Source Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{908BADE7-2A58-333B-AD9B-5E1617448503}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Form Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{9FA839DE-9FEE-30ED-B4E8-82D035CDF7A6}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="GeneratedFiles">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{23EAD13C-71A9-3CDF-95DC-E067B596CE7A}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
</ItemGroup>
```

Why? Is it a cmake bug? How to avoid the problem?

I would like CMake keep the vcxproj.filters file unchanged if all the source files are unchanged.

Maybe there is no problem with single project. My solution has dozens of projects, also C# and C++ projects mixed.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of your CMake code?

Comment: @Florian, Thanks for suggestion. I was trying to provide a simple example, but seems it was not easy to reproduce the problem with simple example. So I asked the question here, in case someone met the same problem.

Comment: I've seen you raised [an issue at CMake's site](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17446) asking the same question. So I assume you already consider this a bug and I admit I don't understand what kind of solution you are looking for or what's the exact problem you're facing when the `.filter` files are different/changing.

Comment: The problem is, I have projects A and B in one VS solution, B depends on A. When building the VS solution, A is built first, in A's post build event, run a tool to generate new files to B if A is changed, when run CMake tool to add the new generated files to project B。If A is unchanged, there are not new files generated to B, then run CMake tool, B should be unchanged in this case, but the .filters file of B is changed by CMake, ask to reload the B project, that is strange and boring.

Comment: Ok. Your problem then is that VS wants to reload the project every time, even if nothing has changed. If you have to run a CMake re-configure-step between building A and B, it sounds like you have to change your CMake setup in the direction of external projects or execute process commands. And sounds like [How to only build auto generated code when the generator or input changes in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193068/how-to-only-build-auto-generated-code-when-the-generator-or-input-changes-in-cma) may be related.

Comment: Not the same, the problem is just that vcxproj.filters ordering is not stable. That's a camke issue. Any workaround for this?