# How to have individual include directories for each subdirectory?

Tags: cmake, directory, include

I have the following directory structure:

```
Root
| - CMakeLists.txt
| - a
| - | - a1.c
| - | - a2.c
| - | - include
| - | - | - a1.h
| - | - | - a2.h
| - b
| - | - b.c
| - | - include
| - | - | - b.h
| - include
| - | - <symlink to a/include>
| - | - <symlink to b/include>
| - | - gen.h
| - main
| - | - main.c
```

I'd like for each c file to be able to access the include directory in the root and the include directory in each of their sub-folders.
So `a1.c` & `a2.c` can `#include <a1.h>` & `#include <a2.h>` directly, but any other file outside of the a sub-directory (like `b.c` or `main.c`) needs to use a more complete path `#include <a/a1.h>`

Note that `a2.c` & `b.c` are dependent on each-other (meaning that `a2.c` uses code defined in `b.c` & vice-versa), so using libraries is not an option (given that `a2.c` won't be able to be compiled unless linked against `b.o` & vice-versa).

At the moment, I have a target defined for `main.elf` which uses code from both `a` & `b`, but using `target_include_directories` will add the include directories for all the source files and `include_directories` won't add them to any.

Does CMake provide a way to do this?

Comment: You may use OBJECT libraries for separate `a2.c` and `b.c`. Actually, STATIC libraries should also work: in CMake it is possible to have interdependent static libraries (linked with `target_link_libraries`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're absolutely right, I hadn't seen that there were more sub-points inside the `target_link_libraries` documentation. OBJECT worked like a charm. If you write this in an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I have found [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802536/how-can-i-specify-an-include-directory-to-use-when-compiling-a-specific-generat) which is ultimately about the same problem: include directories for specific files. While your question looks a bit better for me, the referenced question already has good answers. This is why I marked it as a duplicate target of your one. Note, that on Stack Overflow "duplicate" doesn't mean "bad". And your question post still can collect votes.